# how to upgrade standalone version of graylog

Tags: graylog2

I want to upgrade my standalone graylog2 instance from 1.1.5 to 1.2.1.
I unpacked the new version, copy the old graylog.conf file and data/ directory and after I start the new version I get some errors.

For example if I go to the indices page the graylog-webinterface log says:

```
Caught Exception while deserializing JSON request: 
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Instantiation of [simple type, class org.graylog2.rest.models.system.indexer.responses.IndexRangeSummary] value failed: Null indexName (through reference chain: org.graylog2.rest.models.system.indexer.responses.IndexRangesResponse["ranges"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
    .
    .
    .
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Null indexName
    at org.graylog2.rest.models.system.indexer.responses.AutoValue_IndexRangeSummary.<init>(AutoValue_IndexRangeSummary.java:21) ~[org.graylog2.graylog2-rest-models-1.1.5.jar:na]
    at org.graylog2.rest.models.system.indexer.responses.IndexRangeSummary.create(IndexRangeSummary.java:47) ~[org.graylog2.graylog2-rest-models-1.1.5.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor59.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedMethod.call(AnnotatedMethod.java:120) ~[com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator.createFromObjectWith(StdValueInstantiator.java:227) ~[com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    ... 61 common frames omitted
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you also updated the graylog web.